# Displaying (version control) diff markers/annotations in the line numbers area of VIM

Tags: git, vim, diff

Is there a way to have VIM mark it's line numbers with (git) diff annotations?

For example, Eclipse has the feature of changing the background colour in the line numbers ruler. Modified lines appear as colour X, deleted lines appear as colour Y (as a small mark in the ruler), added lines appear as colour Z.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wow, right on time! I just came across [this (poorly named) script](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1881) yesterday. I don't like this feature in Eclipse so I didn't try the plugin. I can't say if it's any good.

Comment: Thanks -- this worked to a degree, however it didn't properly pick up diffs on files that weren't in the root of the repo. It's possible that my OS is incompatible (says Unix only, I'm on Linux)

Comment: Found a fix in the comments of the author's script page: http://zevv.nl/play/code/vimscripts/